# What does the "that little bubble of accidental arrogance" meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ...  as you initially did, that their design was just behind. It's nice to see an idea that pops that little bubble of accidental arrogance.

The above sentence is from [Nick Johnson's](http://thinkvitamin.com/design/why-is-chinese-web-design-so-bad/) blog on thinkvitamin.  I don't understand and would like for someone to  explain the meaning of the phrase, "that pops that little bubble of accidental arrogance".

PS: I think the second *that* after *pops* is unnecessary; am I right?

Comment: More context please? As in a link of the blog...

Comment: the link : http://thinkvitamin.com/design/why-is-chinese-web-design-so-bad/  the sentence is form a user's comment. you can search ReadyDesigns on the page. thank you

Comment: I think this is the blog you are referring to. http://thinkvitamin.com/design/why-is-chinese-web-design-so-bad/

Comment: yeah,you're right. do you know what's the line meaning? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the blog; The blogger originally stated:

> my initial reaction was “Oh, they are a developing nation and simply haven’t caught up to us yet.”

Then he describes a theory that he formed of why the web designs are like what it is:

> Another possibility, however (and my personal theory), is that nurture has trumped nature and Chinese web design preferences are being formed from upbringing and cultural influence rather than prolonged exposure and natural artistic evolution

The commenter, then states that:

> but always figured, as you initially did, that their design was just behind

But then, due to the blog, she sees the thing from an entirely different viewpoint, and so she states:

> It's nice to see an idea that pops that little bubble of accidental arrogance. Thanks for sharing your thoughts

So, first she thinks, "Oh, Chinese web designs are behind," then she reads the blog, then she changes her mind, so she's like "Oh, it could have been that. That's a new idea to me. That just popped my little bubble of accidental arrogance".

"Accidental Arrogance" meaning [unintended or thoughtless] prejudice towards Chinese web designs.

Comment: i think the second that which after pops is unnecessary . am i right?

Comment: @enjoylife: the second that is an adjective, so it is required. it points to "little bubble"